# How to reduce the run time of a for loop and df.loc in a multiple If statement in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am converting an excel file into pandas/python code that looks like this.

```
      Date Buy Signal Sell Signal
0   13-Apr         No          No
1   12-Apr         No         Yes
2   11-Apr        Yes          No
3   10-Apr        Yes         Yes
4    9-Apr         No          No
5    8-Apr         No         Yes
6    7-Apr        Yes          No
7    6-Apr        Yes         Yes
8    5-Apr         No          No
9    4-Apr         No         Yes
10   3-Apr        Yes          No
11   2-Apr        Yes         Yes
12   1-Apr         No          No
13  31-Mar         No         Yes
14  30-Mar        Yes          No
15  29-Mar        Yes         Yes
16  28-Mar         No          No
17  27-Mar         No         Yes
18  26-Mar        Yes          No
19  25-Mar        Yes         Yes
20  24-Mar         No          No
21  23-Mar         No          No
22  22-Mar         No          No
```

The desired output is something like this.

```
      Date Buy Signal Sell Signal Own the Stock   Buy  Sell
0   13-Apr         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
1   12-Apr         No         Yes           Yes  Hold  Sell
2   11-Apr        Yes          No           Yes  Hold  Hold
3   10-Apr        Yes         Yes            No   Buy  Skip
4    9-Apr         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
5    8-Apr         No         Yes           Yes  Hold  Sell
6    7-Apr        Yes          No           Yes  Hold  Hold
7    6-Apr        Yes         Yes            No   Buy  Skip
8    5-Apr         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
9    4-Apr         No         Yes           Yes  Hold  Sell
10   3-Apr        Yes          No           Yes  Hold  Hold
11   2-Apr        Yes         Yes            No   Buy  Skip
12   1-Apr         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
13  31-Mar         No         Yes           Yes  Hold  Sell
14  30-Mar        Yes          No           Yes  Hold  Hold
15  29-Mar        Yes         Yes            No   Buy  Skip
16  28-Mar         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
17  27-Mar         No         Yes           Yes  Hold  Sell
18  26-Mar        Yes          No           Yes  Hold  Hold
19  25-Mar        Yes         Yes            No   Buy  Skip
20  24-Mar         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
21  23-Mar         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
22  22-Mar         No          No            No  Skip  Skip
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to run these multiple ifs in a given range.

Own the stock column is based on the previous 'Buy' and 'Sell' values.

If the previous day's 'Buy' column is '**Buy**', then the present day's 'Own the stock' column is 'Yes'.

If the previous day's 'Buy' column is '**Hold**' and 'Sell' column is '**Hold**', then the present day's 'Own the stock' column is 'Yes'.

If the previous day's 'Buy' column is '**Hold**' and 'Sell' column is '**Sell**', then the present day's 'Own the stock' column is 'No'.

If the previous day's 'Buy' column is '**Skip**', then the present day's 'Own the stock' column is 'No'.

And likewise, the code below is for the 'Buy' column and 'Sell' column respectively. The problem occurs because 'Own the Stock' column is a function of the previous day's value of 'Buy' and 'Sell'. And the 'Buy' and 'Sell' columns are functions of the present day value of 'Own the Stock'. Somewhat this is recursive in nature that's why, I was not able to use .shift(-1) and np.select. Or perhaps I had a wrong execution of it.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(df), 0, -1):
    i=i-1
    if i == len(df)-1 :
        df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] = "No"
        df.loc[i,'Buy'] = "Skip"
        df.loc[i,'Sell'] = "Skip"
    else :
        #'Own the Stock' Column
        if df.loc[i+1,'Buy'] == "Buy" :
            df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] = "Yes"
        if df.loc[i+1,'Buy'] == "Hold" and df.loc[i+1,'Sell'] == "Hold"  :
            df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] = "Yes"
        if df.loc[i+1,'Buy'] == "Hold" and df.loc[i+1,'Sell'] == "Sell"  :
            df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] = "No"
        if df.loc[i+1,'Buy'] == "Skip" :
            df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] = "No"
        #'Buy' Column
        if df.loc[i,'Buy Signal'] == "No" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "No"  :
            df.loc[i,'Buy'] = "Skip"
        if df.loc[i,'Buy Signal'] == "No" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "Yes"  :
            df.loc[i,'Buy'] = "Hold"
        if df.loc[i,'Buy Signal'] == "Yes" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "No"  :
            df.loc[i,'Buy'] = "Buy"
        if df.loc[i,'Buy Signal'] == "Yes" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "Yes"  :
            df.loc[i,'Buy'] = "Hold"           
        #'Sell' Column
        if df.loc[i,'Sell Signal'] == "No" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "No"  :
            df.loc[i,'Sell'] = "Skip"
        if df.loc[i,'Sell Signal'] == "No" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "Yes"  :
            df.loc[i,'Sell'] = "Hold"
        if df.loc[i,'Sell Signal'] == "Yes" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "No"  :
            df.loc[i,'Sell'] = "Skip"
        if df.loc[i,'Sell Signal'] == "Yes" and df.loc[i,'Own the Stock'] == "Yes"  :
            df.loc[i,'Sell'] = "Sell"
```

Although messy, the code is running ok. If the rows are a couple of thousands it runs around 10-20s. However, when I tried to run it in a number of hundred of thousands, the code is not finishing as intended.

Is there a cythonized or vectorized or simpler pandas version that you can recommend? As I do some reading, these are suggested ways to reduce the run time. However, I was not successful in doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the dataframes there in text (so we can copy-and-paste it)? Also can you briefly describe the logic behind creating the new columns?

Comment: It looks like you're doing something complex(ish?) to each row of the dataframe. An apply function might be better than what you're doing, and would certainly be more readable. There are also likely ways to vectorize it as well, depending on the logic of the operations.

Comment: vectorisation comes from thinking about your logic.  clearly this can be done with `np.select()` and `pd.shift()`. data needs to be text and logic would be better if defined in terms of vectors rather than absolute reference to current loop counter

Comment: As I read similar questions to this, pd.shift() will not work on recursive calculations since 'Own the Stock' column is based on the previous value of 'Buy' and 'Sell' columns, and 'Buy' and 'Sell' columns are based on the present value of 'Own the Stock' column.